# Обновление свойств при использовании ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

К Grid привязана ObservableCollection. Столбцы Grid привязаны к свойствам объектов этой коллекции. При изменении свойства в ячейке Grid или значения свойства во viewmodel привязки работают корректно и обновляются.

Проблема возникает когда я привязываю к Grid ICollectionView который фильтрует ObservableCollection. Фильтр срабатывает, данные отображаются корректно, но когда я изменяю значения ячеек в Grid, в ObservableColection значения не меняются.

```
// ViewModel

private ICollectionView _protections;

public ICollectionView Protections
{
    get { return _protections; }
    set
    {
        _protections = value;
    }
} 

AllProtections = new ObservableCollection<Protection>();
```

Далее наполняю ObservableCollection, и после...

```
Protections = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllProtections);
Protections.Filter = CustomerFilter;

private bool CustomerFilter(object item)
{
    Protection prot = item as Protection;
    if (prot != null)
    {
        return prot.Kind == Kind && prot.Active == Active;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте ICollectionViewLiveShaping, у него есть такая вещь, как `IsLiveFiltering`, которая будет автоматически рефрешить фильтр. Пример можете глянуть к примеру на [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906474/6808809).

Comment: Фильтруйте данные на стороне VM

Comment: @АндрейNOP, код выше как раз из VM. На вьюхе только привязка.

Comment: Ок, просто я считаю `CollectionViewSource` все же "вьюшным" способом фильтрации. А вообще я имел ввиду завести в VM не одну коллекцию, а две — одна для полного списка, вторая для фильтрованного и привязываться именно ко второй

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо за совет, так и поступил в итоге. При попытке завернуть ObservableCollection в ICollectionViewLiveShaping или ICollectionView фильтрация работает корректно, но событие PropertyChanged на вложенных объектах не срабатывает, хотя каждый из них реализовывает INPC. На двух ObservableCollection все работает как и ожидается.